# What is a flaccid grab?

Tags: terminology, tagpro

I see balls getting chastised in chat for performing a 'flaccid grab'? To what manoeuvre does this refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flaccid grab is when you're at the opposing team's base, and their flag is available to capture. You see the opponent's flag carrier coming, ready to capture. You grab the opponent's flag and make your way back to your own base.

This is a bad idea, because if you're popped on the way to your base, the opponent gets a free capture. Instead, you should try to pop the enemy FC before capturing the flag yourself.

Comment: is that just related to this game then? in most other CTF style that term you just described is known as E-Grab or Emergency Grab.

Comment: As far as I know, it's only used in tagpro.